# XSD error: Element is a simple type, so it must have no element information item [children]

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am working on a very basic XML schema and I am receiving

> cvc-type.3.1.2: Element 'creator' is a simple type, so it must have no
>   element information item [children]. [8]

in NetBeans when I attempt to validate XML. I am following the W3 schools tutorial and it seems my code is very similar to theirs. I am confused how the error states creator is a simple type when I declared it as complex. Did I incorrectly declare the creator element as a complex type?

**XML doc:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<gallery
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Proj1Schema.xsd">
    <creator>
        <name>John Doe</name>
    </creator>
</gallery>
```

**Schema:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/gallery"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="creator">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="gallery">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="creator" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
            <xs:element name="creator" type="xs:string"/>
```

with

```
            <xs:element ref="creator"/>
```

to reuse the global declaration of `element` within the content model of `gallery`.  As you had the XSD, `creator` within `gallery` would only allow simple `xs:string` content, contrary to your XML which has complex content, including a `name` child element.

Comment: You have made it clear to me. Thank you for sharing your knowledge! :)